# CATIA-CAA CATIVisu

Tags: api, visual-c++, cad, catia, caa

Hi i need the flow to read the visualisation details from a CATIA V5R18 Part file.

Visualisation details lik,
1.No of Vertices
2.No of Triangles
3.No of Strips
4.No of Fans
5.No of Normal
6.Bouding Sphere Centre and Radius

These details i have red from .cgr files using CAT3DRep/CATRep/CATSurfacicRep...
But i am not able to read the same for .CATPart files.

From .CATPart with the help of CATIVisu i got CAT3DBagRep type When i queried from PartFeatures But to get Visualisation details i need CATSurfacicRep.

Can anyone help?
Wat Interface i should query and from where i should query?

Answer (score 1):

Well, information about the mesh (triangle, strips, fans, etc) is only carried by leaf Reps, like CAT3DSurfacicRep.

For complex files like CATPart or CATProduct, where you have a hierarchy of geometries, there's also a hierarchy of Reps. CAT3DBagRep is the class that allows building this hierarchy, as it has children Reps (which can of course be also CAT3DBagReps).

One solution may be to recursively explore this Rep hierarchy from the root CAT3DBagRep you get. The method to get the children Reps of a CAT3DBagRep is:

```
list<CATRep> *GetChildren();
```

You can go down the Rep tree until you get Reps of the expected type, like CATSurfacicRep. You may find many of them depending on your model.

When retrieving the mesh coordinates, normals and bounding element, please take into account that they are given in local Rep coordinates. A CAT3DBagRep carries positioning and orientation information (used when you position CATProducts, for example). This is returned by the following CAT3DBagRep method:

```
const CAT4x4Matrix * GetMatrix() const;
```

Depending on your scenario/model, you may need to take this positioning information into account.

Comment: @ cma  Thank You .CAT3DBagRep which i got is returning Zero Childrens.  I got CAT3DBagRep type when I queried from CATIGeometricalElement pointer.  Is that right that I should query from GeometricalElement Pointer.  If not where should I query from? I used CATIVisu interface for this.

Comment: For Part Files,what interface I should use to read the tessellation details.